# When I use Stencil - CLI for local development, the local port display of my site is different from the online display

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

I have used the command Stencil start -- Variation and selected the variation that is being used now, but this is the problem, I don't know what the problem is.The local port shows a lot more stuff.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

have you pushed your changed and activated it on the storefront? You can do this with the stencil command stencil push -a [image]

Comment: You may have misinterpreted my meaning. I downloaded my current theme locally and installed the dependencies, and the local port showed up differently than the online one, a lot more stuff, and I'm sure I didn't make any changes to the code. It's not a push problem.

Comment: Yes it appears that I have misunderstood you! Since this is happening after downloading, are you clicking “Download Current Theme” or are you possibly clicking “Download Original Theme” instead? The original theme may have the additional content that the current theme does not. Since this is what you're noticing, this may be happening!

Let us know 